# Twilio Autopilot change previously collected fields

Tags: twilio

I am trying to set up a time and date to schedule an appointment, so I collect the date first and verify that times are available on that date. Then I try to collect a time for that date, if that time does not exist I want the customer to be able to ask something like, "How about Friday at 6pm." and it will change the date. Is there an easy way or workaround to get this functionality?

Comment: Hey Cameron, what have you tried to achieve this so far?

Comment: Hi Phil, I am currently looking at having 5 separate task, one for collecting the service for the appointment (prefilling), one for collecting service and date (prefilling both), one for collecting date, one for collecting time, and one for listening. On the time validation, if the time is available I call my appointment booking api. If not then I transition to the ask task. Both the date and the time tasks have logic that checks that the service is already set. If it is not then it defaults to the ask task again. In the appointment booking api I will stitch everything together.

Comment: The date only and time only tasks have samples for matching input that only contains a date or time respectively.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. I'd recommend carrying on and if you find trouble somehow, then ask a new question that can be debugged.